# TEXT() function not padding as expected in Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, text-formatting

I have an Excel worksheet that has three pages:

1. "Eingaben" / Input - the user types in some data
2. "Export" - the data is formatted and padded for PRN file Export
3. "Konstante" - contains some constant values to be used in export tab

On page one there is a field that contains a number (formatting in input as "Standard"). The given number is "67922200305"

In Export the formula says

```
=TEXT(Konstante!$B$5&Eingabe!$D2;"000000000000000000000000")
```

so the input value is supposed to be prefixed with "60308700" and the whole thing shall be zero-padded to the length of 24.

Strangely the output in Export is:

```
000006030870067922200000
```

where I expected it to be

```
000006030870067922200305
```

The format of the export field is Standard and the constant is Text.

To me it looks like "rounding" issue, though I guess '&' should concatenate the strings.

Comment: It seems that you have setting which turns input values divided by 1000. So the 305 at the end rounds up. Try TEXT(Konstante!$B$5&TEXT(Eingabe!$D2);"000000000000000000000000").

Comment: It does not work as the second parameter to the inner TEXT() function is missing. So I tried =TEXT(Konstante!$B$5&TEXT(Eingabe!$D2;"00000000000");"000000000000000000000000") with the same result, it does not display the last three digits.

Comment: Try to find the setting. I don't know how does it look like in German. It should be on Additional settings tab though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TEXT` function takes a numeric value as first parameter, so the result of the concatenation (ie. `Konstante!$B$5&Eingabe!$D2`) is converted to a number. Note that the same happens to comment suggestion (`Konstante!$B$5&TEXT(Eingabe!$D2))`).

Take a look at this [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_precision_in_Microsoft_Excel):

> Although Excel can display 30 decimal points, its precision for a specified number is confined to 15 significant figures, and calculations may have an accuracy that is even less due to three issues: round off, truncation, and binary storage.

Your number (`6030870067922200305`) is too long, and Excel keeps only 15 significant numbers (ie `603087006792220`).

You can achieve what you are trying to do, dealing with text values exclusively. For example, you could use `LEN` and `REPT` functions:

```
=REPT(0;24-(LEN(Konstante!$B$5)+LEN(Eingabe!$D2)))&Konstante!$B$5&Eingabe!$D2
```

Here, I repeat `0` to reach 24 (less constant and input lengths), then I concat constant and input values.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, this looks promising, I will need to translate the function names to german, I will give you feedback soon.

Comment: There is the (german) tool I use to convert function names from french to english ;) http://excel-translator.de/

Comment: Result: `=WIEDERHOLEN(0;24-(LÄNGE(Konstante!$B$5)+LÄNGE(Eingabe!$D2)))&Konstante!$B$5&Eingabe!$D2`

Comment: Thank you @ssssteffff your solution works for me :-))) *happy*